# tvservice -M command doesn't show any HDMI event changes in Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, hdmi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ device running raspbian and it is connected to an HDMI display. I need to monitor HDMI events like unplugging cable or attaching cable. However when I use `tvservice -M` command as suggested in the Raspberry Pi documentation and if I unplug the HDMI cable and attach again it doesn't catch the event and show nothing. However other tvservice commands like `tvservice -n`, `tvservice -s` are working properly.

Is there any way to catch HDMI events or how to fix this problem?